# How to show connectivity of nodes graphically with PHP?

Tags: php, graph, connectivity

To reflect:

```
A-B
A-C
A-D
..
B-D
..
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible using only PHP. But if you can install programs on the system running PHP you could use [Graphviz's tools](http://www.graphviz.org/) via [exec](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: PHP has the GD library, which you can make images, but you would have to calculate everything yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is a graph visualizer. It can be user to render graphs from string input.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how to make a graph like I described?

Answer (score 0):

[Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) is a flash based visualization package. You could probably use PHP to load your data into a Prefuse based visalization on a webpage. I'm assuming here that this for a web based application.